# Running Orbeon-Form-Builder-Generated-Form with Java Application

Tags: orbeon, xforms

Should I be able to run Orbeon-Form-Builder-Generated-Form with Java Application,

i.e. Copy the source of the Form into a simple.JSP (using separate deployment as mentioned in http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xforms-with-java-applications) ?

I found that the evaluation of **$form-resources** fails. **Why** ?

simple.jsp XML

```
    <xhtml:html xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:xforms="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
                xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
                xmlns:xxi="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xinclude"
                xmlns:xxforms="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms"
                xmlns:exforms="http://www.exforms.org/exf/1-0"
                xmlns:fr="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-runner"
                xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
                xmlns:sql="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/sql"
                xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <xhtml:head>
            <xhtml:title>Simple Form</xhtml:title>
            <xforms:model id="fr-form-model">

                <!-- Main instance -->
                <xforms:instance id="fr-form-instance">
                    <form>
                        <section-1>
                            <control-2/>

                        </section-1>
                        <section-2>
                            <control-3/>
                        </section-2>
                    </form>
                </xforms:instance>

                <!-- Bindings -->
                <xforms:bind id="fr-form-binds" nodeset="instance('fr-form-instance')">
                    <xforms:bind id="section-1-bind" nodeset="section-1">
                        <xforms:bind id="control-2-bind" nodeset="control-2" name="control-2" type="xforms:date"/>

                    </xforms:bind>
                    <xforms:bind id="section-2-bind" nodeset="section-2">
                        <xforms:bind id="control-3-bind" nodeset="control-3" name="control-3"/>
                    </xforms:bind>
                </xforms:bind>

                <!-- Metadata -->
                <xforms:instance id="fr-form-metadata" xxforms:readonly="true">
                    <metadata>
                        <application-name>test</application-name>
                        <form-name>testf</form-name>
                        <title xml:lang="en">Simple Form</title>
                        <description xml:lang="en"/>
                        <author/>
                        <logo mediatype="" filename="" size=""/>
                    </metadata>
                </xforms:instance>

                <!-- Attachments -->
                <xforms:instance id="fr-form-attachments">
                    <attachments>
                        <css mediatype="text/css" filename="" size=""/>
                        <pdf mediatype="application/pdf" filename="" size=""/>
                    </attachments>
                </xforms:instance>

                <!-- All form resources -->
                <!-- Don't make readonly by default in case a service modifies the resources -->
                <xforms:instance id="fr-form-resources" xxforms:readonly="false">
                    <resources>
                        <resource xml:lang="en">
                            <control-3>
                                <label>input 2</label>
                                <hint/>
                                <help/>
                                <alert/>
                            </control-3>
                            <control-2>
                                <label>dATE</label>
                                <hint/>
                                <help/>
                                <alert/>
                            </control-2>
                            <section-1>
                                <label>sec1</label>
                                <help/>
                            </section-1>
                            <section-2>
                                <label>sec2</label>
                                <help/>
                            </section-2>

                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                </xforms:instance>

                <!-- Utility instances for services -->
                <xforms:instance id="fr-service-request-instance" xxforms:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
                    <request/>
                </xforms:instance>

                <xforms:instance id="fr-service-response-instance" xxforms:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
                    <response/>
                </xforms:instance>

            </xforms:model>
        </xhtml:head>
        <xhtml:body>
            <fr:view>
                <xforms:label ref="instance('fr-form-metadata')/title"/>
                <fr:body>
                    <fr:section id="section-1-section" bind="section-1-bind">
                        <xforms:label ref="$form-resources/section-1/label"/>
                        <xforms:help ref="$form-resources/section-1/help"/>
                        <fr:grid columns="1">
                            <xhtml:tr>

                                <xhtml:td>
                                    <xforms:input xmlns:xbl="http://www.w3.org/ns/xbl"
                                                  xmlns:fb="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-builder"
                                                  xmlns:pipeline="java:org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.PipelineFunctionLibrary"
                                                  id="control-2-control"
                                                  bind="control-2-bind">
                                        <xforms:label ref="$form-resources/control-2/label"/>
                                        <xforms:hint ref="$form-resources/control-2/hint"/>
                                        <xforms:help ref="$form-resources/control-2/help"/>
                                        <xforms:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                                    </xforms:input>
                                </xhtml:td>
                            </xhtml:tr>
                        </fr:grid>
                    </fr:section>
                    <fr:section id="section-2-section" bind="section-2-bind">
                        <xforms:label ref="$form-resources/section-2/label"/>
                        <xforms:help ref="$form-resources/section-2/help"/>
                        <fr:grid columns="1">
                            <xhtml:tr>
                                <xhtml:td>
                                    <xforms:input xmlns:xbl="http://www.w3.org/ns/xbl"
                                                  xmlns:fb="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-builder"
                                                  xmlns:pipeline="java:org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.PipelineFunctionLibrary"
                                                  id="control-3-control"
                                                  bind="control-3-bind">
                                        <xforms:label ref="$form-resources/control-3/label"/>
                                        <xforms:hint ref="$form-resources/control-3/hint"/>
                                        <xforms:help ref="$form-resources/control-3/help"/>
                                        <xforms:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                                    </xforms:input>
                                </xhtml:td>
                            </xhtml:tr>
                        </fr:grid>
                    </fr:section>
                </fr:body>
            </fr:view>
        </xhtml:body>
    </xhtml:html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [code to support Form Runner in separate deployment](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/commit/909c0ea738e530f8845f5b6ec04ed9ba0254f35b) was pushed after the 3.9 release. As of this writing, 3.9 is the latest release, so at points you'll need to use a [nightly build](http://www.orbeon.com/forms/download) for this.