# Using Form-Builder-Generated-Form with Java Application

Tags: orbeon, xforms

I tried the approach of using Form-Builder-Generated-Form within Java application suggested here < [Running Orbeon-Form-Builder-Generated-Form with Java Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945099/running-orbeon-form-builder-generated-form-with-java-application) > : downloaded Orbeon nightly build, created a sample form using Form Builder and copy & pasted it into JSP page in my app. However, when I try to access this JSP, it redirects me to: /myapp/fr/unauthorized . Can you please tell me what I maybe doing wrong? Or what is the right way of making Orbeon process Form Builder generated content in Java app?

For my deployment I followed separate deployment and configuration specified in Orbeon documentation. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing anything wrong, but Orbeon Forms doesn't support this type of form deployment.

The [separate deployment](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xforms-with-java-applications#TOC-Separate-deployment) mode runs the output of your JSP directly through the XForms engine.

Form Builder-generated forms OTOH expect pre-processing via the Form Runner runtime, in particular through the [`components.xsl`](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/src/resources/apps/fr/components/components.xsl) XSLT transform. This is needed to support all the Form Runner features, including built-in persistence, error summary, internationalization, etc.

Currently the cleanest way to integrate such forms with your own app is to just run them side by side (Orbeon WAR + your own WAR) and navigate between each other via links and POSTs.

You could also use an iframe, although that is often a disliked solution.

You could also transform the form produced by Form Builder into plain XForms that doesn't assume Form Runner. It wouldn't be too hard to do but would be outside the scope of this StackOverflow question.

Comment: In the post mentioned in my question, it was stated that nightly build version of Orbeon supports this type of deployment. So, I am trying to make it work, however unsuccessful so far.

Comment: @uzrovsh, you are right, I had completely forgotten about that. I am trying to figure out what's the status of this.

Comment: @uzrovsh I am not sure if this is still current, but I have found why this is happening and [committed a fix](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/commit/86fc78ce19c5ad88d0401c0124ced1c915dc3a57). This is still considered experimental though.